# Port gluon gradle project to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, javafx, gluon-mobile

I have this [project](https://github.com/guruprasaad123/WifiSchedular) which I have been working in Eclipse IDE. Now I want to continue this project in **Android Studio**. I have tried `import as gradle project,Eclipse ADT` which did not work. Please help me.

Comment: For some errors Android Studio will suggest the fix with a link. If that doesn't work you will have to post which is the prblem that is not getting resolved.

Comment: Oky , i'll update my question @Juan